# How to add column based in the second line match using SED or another command?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, zgrep

I have the following lines result from `zcat` command

```
1 - URL Template: https://www.test.com

2 - Response: <200 OK,{Server=[nginx], Date=[Wed, 11 May 2022 01:05:06 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```

I want to add the line 2 result from call to first line 1 like this

```
URL Template: https://www.test.com <200 OK,{Server=[nginx], Date=[Wed, 11 May 2022 01:05:06 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Is your input actually three lines? You mention a second line, but you show three lines. Also, is the input exactly as shown, with the numbering, or is some part of that data just annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the simple `awk` command:

```
$ awk -F "1 - |2 - Response:" 'NF>1 {printf "%s",$2} END{print ""}' input_file
URL Template: https://www.test.com <200 OK,{Server=[nginx], Date=[Wed, 11 May 2022 01:05:06 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```

It takes care of empty lines by disregarding them.

It supposes that:

- your two non-empty lines always appear in a fixed sequence order, i.e. first `1 - URL Template: ...` then `2 - Response: ...`.
- no other non-empty lines appear between the two lines you show. If otherwise, then additional logic is needed. Such a change would be straightforward.
- each of the two strings "1 - " and "2 - Response: " appear only once per line and at their beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^1/{:a;N;s/^[^A-Z]*\(.*\)\n[^<]*\(.*\)/\1 \2/;ba}' input_file
URL Template: https://www.test.com  <200 OK,{Server=[nginx], Date=[Wed, 11 May 2022 01:05:06 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 sed '/^$/d' filename| awk 'NR==2{gsub(/.*Response:/,"",$0)}1'|sed "1s/.*-//g"|perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
 URL Template: https://www.test.com  <200 OK,{Server=[nginx], Date=[Wed, 11 May 2022 01:05:06 GMT], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```